# Dúvida ao instanciar objeto em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte linha em meu código:

```
document.all['grid_tipo_prestador_' + ind_operadora].object = new _gridlist(document.all['grid_tipo_prestador_' + ind_operadora]);
```

Confesso, não tenho idéia de onde vem `_gridlist`. Veja que eu tenho um `new _gridlist(...)`, agora esse `_gridlist` neste arquivo só aparece nessa linha e nos demais arquivos, tanto no chamador como no auxiliar não existe esse cara. Como eu posso dar um new dessa forma? Quando usamos C#, damos um new em uma classe já existente, agora em Javascript não sei o que acontece aqui. Como Javascript é muito dinâmico e a sua orientação a objeto é um pouco diferente do C#, de repente ele permite criar um tipo dinamicamente, diferente do C# que preciso instanciar uma classe já existente anteriormente. Gostaria de entender isso.

Comment: tecnicamente JavaScript não é orientado a objeto, mas a protótipos.

Comment: pnet, em algum dos arquivos `*.js` deve ter alguma declaração do gênero `var _gridlist = function() { ... }`, é neste ponto que o `_gridlist` é criado. Caso queira ler mais sobre, aconselho este o seguinte [artigo](http://blog.caelum.com.br/reaproveitando-codigo-com-javascript-heranca-e-prototipos/)

Comment: @TobyMosque, foi isso que eu quis dizer e me fugiu na hora do post. Sendo orientado a protótipo, isso permite a criação de objetos dinamicamente? Pois em javascript, posso afirmar que não existe classes?

Comment: @TobyMosque, você tem razão. Está no arquivo .js referente ao grid em questão. Seu comentário para mim é a resposta. Eu fui preceptado em postar. Me desculpo pela precipitação.

Comment: No ECMAScript 5, não existe uma definição de classe, então o que você pode fazer são objetos e entender os mesmos usando protótipos, no ECMAScript 6 será possível criar classes, mas a maioria dos browsers modernos ainda não tem um suporte ao ES6

Comment: @TobyMosque, cara mais uma vez você salvou minha pátria. Obrigado. Como eu disse, o seu comentário que está votado, resolveu minha situação.